# KDE Plasma disappearing after application launch

Tags: desktop-environment, plasma5

Whenever I launch an application (like this google chrome, which I'm using to ask this question) the taskbar and desktop become unclickable. Within seconds, the taskbar slides down (animated) and then the desktop turns black (crash?). How do I fix this? (It was working fine this morning.)

This was an `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` from a normally headless installation.

Comment: I'd like to note this was an `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` from a normally headless installation.

Comment: Would have prefered to approve the edit myself, tyvm.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems a simple reinstall fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```